# 'JSON Parse error Unrecognised Token '<' ' ERROR on POST request from React-Native's Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
export default class Broadcast extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this._loadInitialState().done();
    }
    _loadInitialState=async()=>{
        var user= await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        console.log(user+'*********************')
        if(user!==null){
            this.setState({
                username:user
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        this.broadcastList();
    return ( 
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.wrapper}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>Broadcast Page</Text>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
  broadcastList=()=>{
      console.log(this.state.username);
        fetch(`http://192.168.137.1:3000/getBroadcastList?id=${this.state.username}`,{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            })
        }) //backend IP :')
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((res)=>{
            if(res.success===true){
                AsyncStorage.setItem('changeInBroadcastList',false);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('broadcastList',res.broadcastList);

            }
            else{
                AsyncStorage.setItem('loginSuccess',false);
                alert(res.message);
            }
        })
        .done();
    }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper:{
        flex:1
    },
    container:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff0f0',
        paddingLeft: 40,
        paddingRight: 40
    },
    header:{
        fontSize: 24,
        marginBottom:60,
        color:'#000000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    textInput:{
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        padding:16,
        marginBottom:20,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
    },
    btn:{
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor:'#f0f0ff',
        padding:20,
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})
```

Please forgive me for my bad english. I am new to Javascript and I'll try my best to explain my error. The Above code Contains my 'Broadcast' screen. I am setting the `username`'s state by taking the value `'user'` as stored in my AsyncStorage.

After successfully storing the value int the `this.state.username` I am calling `this.broadcastList();` in `render()` , which then makes a POST request to a server.

My Node.js Server is running like a charm, and is successfully returning JSON to the Postman's output console.

[This picture Depicts the successfully running Server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCN5p.png)

But when i try to access my Broad cast screen, this arrow appears.

```
JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
tryCallOne
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14
<unknown>
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25
<unknown>
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:297:23
_callTimer
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:154:6
_callImmediatesPass
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:202:17
callImmediates
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:466:11
__callImmediates
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:329:4
<unknown>
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:147:6
__guardSafe
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:316:6
flushedQueue
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:146:17
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
    Z:\saic\crossplatform\brodSaic\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:11
```

Please Correct me for my Basic mistakes in the question, and Help me to resolve this issue. I'll be very much thankful.

Comment: So to correct you "basic mistake" the `<` is actually the very first character of `<html>` or such a similar tag being returned from your API `getBroadcastList` endpoint, likely as an "error" on the server. There's either a problem with that code, or the error page is a `404` because you actually have the incorrect URL. Check the result of the endpoint in your browser or other testing point first.

Comment: Yes, it seems like html is being returned instead of JSON. and now i get to know why the specific character is `<` . Though, i tested the app in Postman, by providing the same URL to get `JSON` response. I have attached a **picture** with the question above, of my postman's response to URL's POST request, and it is working like charm. I'll try to find the error in my code according to your given suggestion and check for `404` . Thank you.

Comment: This issue was resolved. There was a sure error in the URL. Thank you @NeilLunn

Comment: i am having the same problem i have tested my api with postman and i've also tested the url/endpoint on the browser , it returns json file. what could be the problem?

Comment: @JonasModie , if you are getting '<' token error, then it is sure that the response coming is not a json. You might want to share more information regarding your question.